# "Lines through the Origin and the Intersection of a Curve and a Line." That's a topic from my textbook. I would like you to clarify it to me.

Tags: geometry

[image]From textbook:

> Let $PQR$ be a curve $$ax^2 + 2hxy + by^2 + 2gx + 2fy + c = 0 \qquad (i)$$
>   and $PR$ be the line $$lx + my = n \qquad (ii)$$
>   If $P$ and $R$ be their points of intersection, we have to find the equation of $OP$ and $OR$. Now writing $lx + my = n$ as $(lx+my)/n = 1$, and making $(i)$ homogeneous with its help, we get,
>   $$ax^2 + 2hxy + by^2 + 2gx\frac{lx+my}{n} +2fy\frac{lx+my}{n} + c\left(\frac{lx+my}{n}\right)^2 = 0\qquad (iii)$$
>   This is a second degree homogeneous equation.
>   So, it represents two lines through the origin and through $P$ and $Q$.

What I don't understand here is how by substituting $1$ by $(lx+my)/n$ makes the obtained homogenous equation passing through $P$ and $R$??????